# javascript if else navigator.platform

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, navigator

I have a site that is accessed by raspberry pis and everything else. I need to display a keypad when the a PI access the site and not when everything else access is. I figured i would run a simple platform check as a PI returns Linux armv6l and everything else will return Win32. But i can not get a simple test of the logic to work.

my Javascript browswer.js in static/js

```
function myFunction(){
if( /Linux armv6l|Linux armv7l/i.test(navigator.platform) ) {
txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
}
else    {
txt= "<p>Browser Language: " + navigator.language + "</p>";
}
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;
}
```

my HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>test</title>
    </head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome</h1>

<p id="example"></p>



</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/browser.js"></script>
</html>
```

I am very new to Javascript and HTML so i am sure i am doing a few things wrong but i cannot figure it out. thanks

Comment: I recommend just showing the keypad anyway, but making it so that you have to click something to open it. You can't assume that if someone has a RPi he doesn't have a keyboard, and if he doesn't have a RPi, then he does have a keyboard. There are other possibilities where people might want a keypad, and there are situations where people might have a keyboard attached to their RPi.

Comment: what does this statement do? /Linux armv6l|Linux armv7l/i.test(navigator.platform

Comment: If I understand this correctly, and I do not think I do. It should test to see if the output of i.test(navigator.platform) is == to ether Linux armv6l or Linux armv7l. If yes than the if is true or if not it is false and then the else code should kick in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function systemdetect()
{
systemname=navigator.platform;

if (systemname.indexOf("Linux armv6l")!=-1) {
    systemname="pi"
    document.write("<p>this is a test.</P>")
    }

else {if (systemname.indexOf("Win32")!=-1) {
    systemname="MS 32"
    document.write("<p>this is a Win32 tes.</P>")   

}

else {systemname="N/A"}};

}
```

is what i ended up using to test for PI